# get count number of records which respectively exist in another table with null value also

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

i have two tables. 'listing_messages' and 'listing_message_history'.

```
listing_messages  
=============  
message_id   listing_id    listing_user   third_party_user  
1            162           7              32  
2            162           7              33  
3            162           7              12  

listing_message_history  
======================  
listing_message_history   message_id  is_checked  
1                         1           0  
2                         1           1  
3                         1           1  
4                         2           0  
5                         2           1  
6                         3           0
```

Search criteria==> listing_user=7, is_checked=1
**I want result..**

```
message_id    count_of_unread_message_history  
12         
2             1    
3             0
```

I have made a query is

```
SELECT count(`lmh`.`message_history_id`) AS COUNT,
       `lmh`.`message_id`
FROM `listing_message_history` AS `lmh`
LEFT JOIN `listing_messages` AS `lm` ON `lmh`.`message_id` = `lm`.`message_id`
WHERE `lm`.`third_party_user`=7
  AND `lmh`.is_checked=1
GROUP BY `lm`.`message_id`
```

but it does not returns message_id with count = 0 which message_id do not   have is_checked=1

Comment: how you have tabbed the table records to format these text
?

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you use `left join`, filter conditions on the second table should go in the `on` clause not the `where` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT count(`lmh`.`message_history_id`) AS COUNT,
       `lmh`.`message_id`
FROM `listing_message_history` `lmh` LEFT JOIN
     `listing_messages` `lm`
     ON `lmh`.`message_id` = `lm`.`message_id` AND
        `lm`.`third_party_user` = 7
WHERE `lmh`.is_checked = 1
GROUP BY `lmh`.`message_id`;
```

In addition, you should use the first table for the `group by`, not the second table.

Comment: can you make a query fir this?